# API for flight prices

Tags: api

Does a flight prices API exists ?

I wonder how sites like www.skyscanner.com work.

Do they have contract with flight company or are these informations public ?

I would like to have informations for example as JSON or XML.

Comment: http://api.skyscanner.net/api/ajax/snippets/search-panel/introduction.html is what I got as first result from google for  searching "flight prices api"

Comment: I already found it too, but it only build a flash map on the website and then redirect to skyscanner.com. What I would like to have is are the informations for example as JSON or XML.

Answer (score 5):

The one that has been around the longest that I am aware of is [Sabre](http://www.sabretravelnetwork.com/home/solutions/developer/). I integrated an IVR system to it about a decade ago.  It handles flight and other travel information.  I think it is a bit pricey though.  Here is another [QA on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011123/is-there-an-api-for-booking-flights-and-or-cruises).